# ASP web.config authorization to new roles added by users

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization, roles

I've been searching around the internet and I can't find an exact solution. Sorry it's a bit long but I'm hoping someone can help me.

I'm working on a web-based system using ASP.Net (4.0). This system allows an administrator to add new roles. Apart from adding new roles, the administrator can also set permissions to a role to access different pages.

For example, by default the User role can only access the Home page and. Say the administrator decides to set a new permission to this role and allows it to access another page (for example: ManageUsers.aspx)

I am using the Forms Authentication via the web.config. The web-pages are in two separate folders, one for each role (Admin and User). In each folder another web.config defines which roles can access the pages in this folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="2"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that if the administrator grants access to the User role for a page (for example: ManageUsers.aspx) that is allocated in the Admin folder, the User role is denied access to this page since only an Admin role can access these pages.

The first solution I thought of was changing the web.config on run-time but this will restart the application every time the web.config is changed.

The second solution is listing the pages each role can access from a database table or an XML file. I'm not sure if it will work if I still use the Forms Authentication. Shall I use locations in the web.config files? Or maybe there's another way to solve this? I can't get my head around it.

Thanks in advance for any help!